# Powershell AD Group creation script

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

I am making an AD Group creation script

```
New-ADGroup -Name "CS-WS-PROD-Admin" -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -Path "$OU" -Description "Admin Rights on PROD" -ManagedBy CS-WS-SAR-ADMINS -OtherAttributes @{info="test"}
```

In this script I need to set the ManagedBy option and check that the manager (`CS-WS-SAR-ADMINS`) can update the member list selection.
Currently, this script sets the user name, but is not selecting the option "Manager can update membership list" in the ADUC GUI. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox seems to just give Write permissions to the manager, for the membership of the group.
You can't do it with the `New-ADGroup` cmdlet, but should be able to do it with a second line using `Set-ACL`.